# Using Amazon S3 for customer images and thumbnails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I see on the Lambda support pages there are examples of scripts to create thumbnail images in a separate bucket any time an image is uploaded. But I'm looking at using S3 to upload customer image files for multiple customers. We will likely use something like dropzone.js for handling the uploads and I've already built a working example to upload to an existing bucket.
But since we will be dealing with multiple customers, I'm wondering what the best-practices for handling different customer files is when used in conjunction with S3 and especially with the need to display thumbnails to the customer.

I note the Lambda solution appears to use a pre-configured bucket including all of the necessary permissions and event triggers to run the script. I'm not as familiar with node.js and have done very little in Java or python, and I'm new to the aws environment.

Should I create a new bucket for each customer? Can I? Do I have to add new lambda createThumbnail permissions/event-triggers every time a new bucket is created for a new customer?

Is there a better way to do this?

I would also be curious to know (being new to node.js and aws) how difficult it would be to build a cached thumbnail only when it was requested as opposed to trying to build one whenever a file is uploaded.

SW

Comment: What are your business requirements regarding customers and images? Will each customer have their own collection of images, that should be accessible only to one customer? Should the images themselves all be accessible to anyone who knows the URL, or do you want to ensure that they are only available to the image "owners"? How will your customers be using the images — will they be referring to them from their own website, or are the images only for use within your application? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: yes, each customer their own images only accessible to them. Large files generally, highest resolution possible for printing. They should be 'finished' form so customers should not need to see full resolution often, but thumbnail sizes are used for cart previews, proof sheets and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same bucket with each sub-folder containing thumbnails images for each customer/user (You can name each folder with ${user_id} or something similar)

The workflow could be

1. Full image is uploaded to S3 to customer sub-folder with from your UI (dropzone.js or whatever)
2. Upon success upload. Use S3 object creation event to trigger your Lambda to process & generate a thumbnail. (putting it in thumbnail sub-fol
   dr is an option).
   `Ex:
   YOUR_NEW_BUCKET
   |
   ----customer_1
      |
      ___Image1.png
      ___Image2.jpg
      ___Thumbnails
         |
         ___Image1.png
         ___Image2.jpg`

Comment: how do you restrict it so a given customer can only see the context of their images?

Comment: First, make sure your bucket is not publicly accessible. Probably the best solution is to integrate with AWS Cognito (require user login), get a temporary credentials (after login success) & use it to upload to S3 from user browser. (javascript code with AWS SDK) .

Comment: I assume that since we will be displaying the thumbnails via our web server, I can just set up permissions for the server then limit what is shown to what user by the server itself using those permissions? I don't think there will be a direct need for customers to access the images full size 'on' AWS as they uploaded them to begin with.